# My method outputs Error: java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java, runtime-error, java.util.scanner

First of all, I have say that I am new to all this so please go easy on me guys.

I have been given a task to create a method called `loadLeague()` which despite all my efforts, has proved quite tough going! I wonder if you could help me. The task itself is about football league tables. My method compiles without any problem but then it outputs the "InputMismatchException" error on the Main (or any other standard output). I am literally pulling my hair off (well, what's left of it) and I wonder what I am doing wrong as I have read all my books on Java to the letter!! Could you lovely experts please have a look at my code below and point me into the right direction?

Thanks a bunch guys!!

P.S. I just wanted to say thank you to this forum as it has helped me land my first real job in IT. I rarely comment or ask questions here but I read the comments and questions asked by other people every night, and these really helped with my interviews. So thank you so much!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**  
 * Class League - An instance of this class represents the teams in a
 * football (or similar) league. It provides a class method for creating
 * a new instance of League by reading the data for the teams from a CSV
 * file.
 * 
 * @author Lewis Jones 
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class League
{
   /* instance variables */
   private String name;  // The name of the league
   private Team[] teams; // An array to hold the teams in the league

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class League. It sets the name of the league
    * to the String object provided as the first argument and initialises teams
    * to an array of the size provided as the second argument. This constructor 
    * is private as it is intended for use only by the class method loadLeague().
    */
   private League(String aName, int size)
   {
      super();
      this.name = aName;
      this.teams = new Team[size];
   }

   /* class method */
   /**
    * This method creates a new League object by reading the required details from
    * a CSV file. The file must be organised as follows:
    *     name(String), number of teams (int)
    *     team name(String), won(int), drawn(int), lost(int), for(int), against    (int)
    *        and so on for each team
    * Having created the new League object the method should create all the Team 
    * objects (using the data in the file to set their attributes) and add them 
    * to the teams array.
    */
   public static League loadLeague()
   {
      League theLeague = null;
      String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
      File aFile = new File(pathname);
      Scanner bufferedScanner = null;

      try
      {
         String leagueName;
         int numberOfTeams;

         String teamName;
         int won;
         int drawn;
         int lost;
         int goalsFor;
         int goalsAgainst;
         Scanner lineScanner;
         String currentLine;
         bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader (aFile)));    

         while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
         {
            currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

            leagueName = bufferedScanner.next();
            numberOfTeams = bufferedScanner.nextInt();

            teamName = bufferedScanner.next();
            won = lineScanner.nextInt();
            drawn = lineScanner.nextInt();
            lost = lineScanner.nextInt();
            goalsFor = lineScanner.nextInt();
            goalsAgainst = lineScanner.nextInt();

            Team aTeam = new Team(lineScanner.next());
            aTeam.setWon(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setDrawn(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setLost(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsFor(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsAgainst(lineScanner.nextInt());
            Team[] teams = new Team[numberOfTeams];
            teams[numberOfTeams] = aTeam;
            numberOfTeams++;
            theLeague = new League(leagueName, numberOfTeams);
         }
      }  
      catch (Exception anException)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            bufferedScanner.close();
         }
         catch (Exception anException)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
         }
      }
      return theLeague;
   }

   /* instance methods */

   /**
    * Displays the league table in tabular format to the standard output
    */
   public void display()
   {
      System.out.println(this.name);
      System.out.format("%20s %2s %2s %2s %2s %2s %2s %    2s\n","","P","W","L","D","F","A","Pt");
      for (Team eachTeam : this.teams)
      {
         System.out.format("%20s %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d\n",
                       eachTeam.getName(), eachTeam.getPlayed(), 
                       eachTeam.getWon(), eachTeam.getDrawn(), 
                       eachTeam.getLost(),eachTeam.getGoalsFor(), 
                       eachTeam.getGoalsAgainst(), eachTeam.getPoints());        
      }
   }

   /**
    * Arrange the elements of teams in their natural order. This will only
    * work if a natural order has been defined for the class Team.
    */
   public void sort()
   {
      // to be written later...
   }
}
```

Edit: below is the sample (input) file that came with this task. My apologies. I completely forgot to include this with my post last night.

```
Scottish League Division 1,10
Airdrie United ,3,2,11,14,25
Clyde          ,5,7,4,21,17
Dundee         ,7,2,7,21,18
Gretna         ,10,3,3,43,20
Hamilton Acas  ,7,5,4,19,20
Livingstone    ,6,6,4,21,15
Partick Thistle,8,4,4,25,29
Queen of South ,3,3,10,11,31
Ross County    ,4,4,8,14,24
St Johnstone   ,6,6,4,26,16
```

Comment: It might be handy to show the exception stack trace and identify which lines are the numbered ones identified on it.

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for your comments. Yeah, I thought about that but unfortunately I don't how to show exception stack trace. And because my code is enclosed in a try-catch block, I have no way of knowing where the error is happening. Could you identify any ways of showing the exception stack trace?

Comment: `try ( ... ) catch (XXException e) { e.printStackTrace() }` and fill in your code where the ... is and your exception type for my XXException. This writes the trace to the console. It just gives more info than `System.out.print(e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know exactly where the problem is. Your input file is not formatted correctly. For example, when you are expecting an "int", you are reading a different format, like a string. Since I don't have your input, here is a quick example to show you how that exception gets generated:

The sample file contains the following lines:

**Sample.txt**

1,8,6,3
1,2,***invalid***,3

as you'll see, only the first line of the Sample.txt will be printed since the second line generates the error.
**Output:**
1, 8, 6, 3

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at staxpro.StAXPro.main(StAXPro.java:35)
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("Sample.txt")));
            while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
                Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
                lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

                int first = lineScanner.nextInt();
                int second = lineScanner.nextInt();
                // Here is where I read a string than an int value
                // on the 2nd line of the input file
                int third = lineScanner.nextInt();
                int forth = lineScanner.nextInt();


                System.out.println(first + ", " + second + ", " + third + ", " + forth);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Just a quick look at your code + your input file, I found another problem:

```
teamName = bufferedScanner.next();
            won = lineScanner.nextInt();
            drawn = lineScanner.nextInt();
            lost = lineScanner.nextInt();
            goalsFor = lineScanner.nextInt();
            goalsAgainst = lineScanner.nextInt();

            Team aTeam = new Team(lineScanner.next());
            aTeam.setWon(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setDrawn(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setLost(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsFor(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsAgainst(lineScanner.nextInt());
```

can you spot it ? You read #wins, #drawns, ... etc and you store them in **won**, **drawn**, **lost**, **goalsFor**, **goalsAgainst**, but when you are to create your Team object, you will read NEXT values from your scanner. So basically , you will always read every other line !! Remove everything but keep this section instead:

```
        Team aTeam = new Team(lineScanner.next());
        aTeam.setWon(lineScanner.nextInt());
        aTeam.setDrawn(lineScanner.nextInt());
        aTeam.setLost(lineScanner.nextInt());
        aTeam.setGoalsFor(lineScanner.nextInt());
        aTeam.setGoalsAgainst(lineScanner.nextInt());
```

so based on the above, in your input file, each line must have:
**String**, **int**, **int**, **int**, **int**, **int**
but if you notice, your first line of input file is:

```
Scottish League Division 1,10
```

Which is a **String**, **int**, **int**. Fix these and you should be good to go.
This is just my observation and haven't actually run your code. So I might be missing something. If you still have problems after fixing these, let me know.

**EDIT (2):**
I modified your code and made the corrections. I ran it against this input:

```
Scottish League Division 1,10
Airdrie United ,3,2,11,14,25
Clyde          ,5,7,4,21,17
Dundee         ,7,2,7,21,18
Gretna         ,10,3,3,43,20
Hamilton Acas  ,7,5,4,19,20
Livingstone    ,6,6,4,21,15
Partick Thistle,8,4,4,25,29
Queen of South ,3,3,10,11,31
Ross County    ,4,4,4,14,24
St Johnstone   ,6,6,4,26,16
```

and it works fine. Let me know if there is any other issue.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**  
 * Class League - An instance of this class represents the teams in a
 * football (or similar) league. It provides a class method for creating
 * a new instance of League by reading the data for the teams from a CSV
 * file.
 * 
 * @author Lewis Jones 
 * @version 1.0
 */

public class League
{
   /* instance variables */
   private String name;  // The name of the league
   private Team[] teams; // An array to hold the teams in the league

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class League. It sets the name of the league
    * to the String object provided as the first argument and initialises teams
    * to an array of the size provided as the second argument. This constructor 
    * is private as it is intended for use only by the class method loadLeague().
    */
   private League(String aName, Team[] teams)
   {
      super();
      this.name = aName;
      this.teams = teams;
   }

   /* class method */
   /**
    * This method creates a new League object by reading the required details from
    * a CSV file. The file must be organised as follows:
    *     name(String), number of teams (int)
    *     team name(String), won(int), drawn(int), lost(int), for(int), against    (int)
    *        and so on for each team
    * Having created the new League object the method should create all the Team 
    * objects (using the data in the file to set their attributes) and add them 
    * to the teams array.
    */
   public static League loadLeague()
   {
      League theLeague = null;
      String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
      File aFile = new File(pathname);
      Scanner bufferedScanner = null;

      try
      {
         String leagueName;
         int numberOfTeams;

         String teamName;
         int won;
         int drawn;
         int lost;
         int goalsFor;
         int goalsAgainst;
         Scanner lineScanner;
         String currentLine;
         bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader (aFile)));    
         boolean firstLine = true;
         List<Team> teamsList = new ArrayList<Team>();
         Team[] teams = null;
         while (bufferedScanner.hasNextLine())
         {
            currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

            if (firstLine) {
                // you originally used "bufferedScanner" which actually 
                // gets the values on the next line, not the current line
                leagueName = lineScanner.next();
                numberOfTeams = lineScanner.nextInt();
                firstLine = false;
                continue;
            }

            Team aTeam = new Team(lineScanner.next());
            aTeam.setWon(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setDrawn(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setLost(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsFor(lineScanner.nextInt());
            aTeam.setGoalsAgainst(lineScanner.nextInt());
            teamsList.add(aTeam);

         }
         teams = teamsList.toArray(new Team[]{});
         theLeague = new League(leagueName, teams);
      }  
      catch (Exception anException)
      {
         System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            bufferedScanner.close();
         }
         catch (Exception anException)
         {
            System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
         }
      }
      return theLeague;
   }

   /* instance methods */

   /**
    * Displays the league table in tabular format to the standard output
    */
   public void display()
   {
      System.out.println(this.name);
      System.out.format("%20s %2s %2s %2s %2s %2s %2s %    2s\n","","P","W","L","D","F","A","Pt");
      for (Team eachTeam : this.teams)
      {
         System.out.format("%20s %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d %2d\n",
                       eachTeam.getName(), eachTeam.getPlayed(), 
                       eachTeam.getWon(), eachTeam.getDrawn(), 
                       eachTeam.getLost(),eachTeam.getGoalsFor(), 
                       eachTeam.getGoalsAgainst(), eachTeam.getPoints());        
      }
   }

   /**
    * Arrange the elements of teams in their natural order. This will only
    * work if a natural order has been defined for the class Team.
    */
   public void sort()
   {
      // to be written later...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much Bashir for your elaborate and concise answer! I'm sorry I couldn't reply sooner, I went to bed after posting the question as I was so tired. I am reviewing my code now (in line with your answer) and hopefully everything works out well afterwards. BTW, I have added the sample file that I forgot to include last night, so if you would like to check it out again I'd really appreciate it. Thanks again Bashir.

Comment: @LewisJones, np, I have added a bit more explanation. Check out the edit section.

Comment: Hey Bashir! Thanks again for that input (and for coming back to me). I have fixed my code as you instructed, and now I am getting the: "java.util.InputMismatchException
  in java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
  in java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
  in java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
  in java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
  in League.loadLeague(League.java:75)
  in (Workspace:1)" error. What do you reckon could be the issue??

Comment: @LewisJones  try it with the first line as "Scottish League Division ,1,10,3,4,5" Notice the "," between "Scottish League Division" and "1", also if possible include your corrected input file as well as the code!

Comment: Sorry, I apparently didn't read your code fully. I think I figured what happens exactly. you have these 2 lines `leagueName = bufferedScanner.next();
            numberOfTeams = bufferedScanner.nextInt();` in the while loop which basically only apply to the first line of your input file. However, you read them on every single line. read my edit2 section for a work around !!

Comment: @LewisJones one more thing I corrected in your code was the constructor for your League class. If you notice, you only pass the # of your teams to it instead of your Team array. So basically you wasted time loading them!!